# Build native modules with electron-builder for different OS

Tags: electron, electron-builder, native-module

I'm creating an app using `electron` and `nodejs`, when I try to build it with `electron-builder` using following command:

```
electron-builder --mac --linux --win --x64
```

it builds native modules only for my current os. Is there a way to build native modules for all operating systems?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can't. https://www.electron.build/multi-platform-build

```
If your app has native dependency, 
it can be compiled only on the target platform unless prebuild is not used.

prebuild is a solution, but most node modules don't provide prebuilt binaries.
macOS Code Signing works only on macOS. Cannot be fixed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@centrid/native-modules-prebuilds-creator (homepage: https://github.com/centridsol/native-module-prebuilds-creator) . It allows you to create multiple prebuilds for your native node dependencies and then use those prebuilds whilst building your electron app